# Trouble serving static files other than .html files

Tags: go, go-gin, static-files

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    fmt.Println("Server running on port 3000!")

    // Serve static files
    r.Static("/static/videos", "./static/videos")
    r.Static("/static/css", "./static/css")
    r.Static("/static/img", "./static/images")
    r.Static("/static/fonts", "./static/fonts")
    r.Static("/static/js", "./static/js")

    // Load HTML templates
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("./static/*.html")

    // Handling the routes
    r.GET("/", RootRoute)
    r.GET("/reservation", ReservationRoute)

    log.Fatal(r.Run(":3000"))
}

func RootRoute(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", gin.H{})
}

func ReservationRoute(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "reservation.html", gin.H{})
}
```

This is the code for a simple web server I tried to create using Gin. The files structure is:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIkzR.png)

The problem I am facing is in the web page, only the html file is getting loaded and none of the static files.

Here I am explicitly mentioned every static files in a trial and error basis as nothing was working. I am new to Go so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are trying to access the website - and which website you are trying to access?

Comment: @AryanMehrotra I am just testing them out locally on port 3000. And for both the routes only the html doc is loading in the browser. You can check the file structure for more details, in the attached image above.

Comment: I will try to run and check the same, meanwhile you can try using another framework which I prefer GoFr 
I am attaching a doc on how you can render static files.

https://gofr.dev/docs/v1/advanced-guide/static-file-server
https://github.com/gofr-dev/gofr